# Is "Bowgentle's Fleeting Journey" overpowered as a 5th-level spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, adnd-2e, conversion

*Bowgentle's Book* from “Pages From the Mages” makes a cameo in *Lost Mine of Phandelver* in the D&D 5th Edition Starter Set. If the characters ever find this book, it will contain a couple of unique spells, including *Bowgentle's Fleeting Journey*. I've created a 5e spell inspired by the one from “PFtM”:

> #### Bowgentle's Fleeting Journey
>
> *5th-level conjuration*
>
> **Casting Time:** 1 action
>   **Range:** Touch
>   **Components:** V, S, M (a small ball of uncured rubber)
>   **Duration:** 1 round
>
> You touch one creature other than yourself and choose a location that you can clearly see within 500 feet. The creature is instantly teleported to that location along with anything it is wearing or carrying. If the creature is unwilling, you must make a melee spell attack. At the start of your next turn, the creature is teleported back to its original location. The creature can otherwise perform actions normally for the duration.
>       A maximum of 500 pounds of creature and equipment can be transported by this spell. If the creature is Grappled, Restrained, or loaded with more weight than it can carry, the teleportation fails.
>       If the return location is occupied by another creature or object when the duration ends, the target of this spell does not return to that location and must make a Charisma saving throw or be pushed into the Astral Plane. On a successful save, the target takes 4d6 points of force damage.
>       ***At Higher Levels.*** If this spell is cast with a slot of 6th level or higher, for each level above 5th the maximum teleport distance increases by 250 feet, the maximum weight by 250 pounds, and the duration increases by 1 round.

My question: is this spell overpowered at 5th level, or does it need to be an even higher-level spell to be balanced? If cast outside, you would just need to make a melee spell attack against an enemy and you could teleport it 200 feet into the air. Unless the creature has feather falling or some kind of flying capability, it will plummet to the ground, taking 20d6 points of damage. Or you could push any creature into the Astral plane by touching it, teleporting it out of range, and then stepping into its space.

Compare with *Plane Shift*, which is a 7th-level spell. Fleeting Journey is essentially Plane Shift with a delay of 1 round and only the Astral Plane as the target, instead of being able to choose any plane of existence.

Also compare with *Banishment*, which is a 4th-level spell. Fleeting Journey is like Banishment with a delay of 1 round, fixed to the Astral Plane, no concentration requirement, and the ability to permanently banish any creature, as opposed to only creatures not native to the current plane.

Comment: The system is flagging this post for having an unusual number of edits. It looks like most of them have been minor tweaks to the text of the spell… but the question was answered nearly a year ago. Can I ask what the purpose of these tiny tweaks are? (They do not seem to have anything to do with clarifying the question in order to get accurate answers.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 5e, spells which deal damage require an Attack roll or a Saving throw. Without one of those, this spell would be OP at 5th level. Since this spell requires an attack roll, the damage that you can deal by teleporting an enemy 200 ft into the air seems balanced to me. Compare for example with the 10d6+40 damage for *Disintegration* (level 6) or the 8d8 damage to multiple creatures (cone) for *Cone of Cold* (level 5).

Comment: The original version of the spell also included "Saving throw: negates". For 5E, either a Dex save (to avoid the touch) or a Wis save (to resist the effect) seems most appropriate.

Comment: Charisma, which is used to resist banishment by force of will, also seems appropriate.

Comment: Most touch attack spells require a melee spell attack roll, you can add the same thing in here. The group I play with uses the assumption that a spell isn't instant and so you need to maintain contact, which requires a successful attack roll

Comment: I've edited the spell description to include a melee spell attack. Thanks! I think I agree that this makes it fairly balanced.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single creature to deal with, a 5th level spell might be a rather high level slot to use up unless the creature is very powerful, in which case it's likely to have some magic resistance or other countermeasure (such as plane traveling ability) that reduces the likelihood of this becoming a one-shot solution.  As a GM, I'd be prone to letting it work once or twice, then having enemies mostly equipped with something that prevents unwilling teleports.